# Change ChoiceField option after clean method in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.4

Is there any way to change a form element after the form is cleaned?

There's some form logic that is affected by other fields. In certain cases I want to add an additional choice to a `ChoiceField` after the clean function runs if the form is invalid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You run the clean method _after_ the user submits. The request is sent to the view/models after the clean method, not to the template/browser. You might want to revisit your workflow

Comment: @karthikr I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not clear on why you thought my question had anything to do with the browser or the rendered template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user who submits an invalid form should be rewarded with additional options? Does not make sense to me... but yeah you can always change the choices available in a form field:

```
def clean(self):
    self.fields['some_choice_field'].choices = [[1,'one'],[2, 'two'],[None, 'I refuse to answer']]
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where certain input will trigger choices that the user has to make -- simple example would be a case where there's already an existing record, so now you have to choose whether to update or overwrite the record.